Install4J -> how to I do a programaticly, headlessly update of a service
I wrote a very simple demo project that has a background service that is just running a telnet server that can process CLI commands so that I could figure out how to do a programatic, headless update.  The problem seems to be two fold: First, how to configure the installer project for so that I have a GUI installer for originally installing the service and second, once installed, what are the API calls that I need to do in order to do a headless update.
I wrote the following commands that I can execute through my applications CLI:
   @Command(abbreviation = "updateChecker")
    public String updateChecker() {
        try {
            final String updateUrl = Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.updatesUrl");
            final UpdateDescriptor updateDescriptor = UpdateChecker.getUpdateDescriptor(updateUrl, ApplicationDisplayMode.UNATTENDED);
            if (updateDescriptor.getPossibleUpdateEntry() != null) {
                return updateDescriptor.getPossibleUpdateEntry().getFileName();
            } else {
                return "No update";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Command(abbreviation = "isUpdateScheduled")
    public String isUpdateScheduled() {
        try {
            final String updateUrl = Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.updatesUrl");
            if (UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled()) {
                return "true";
            } else {
                return "false";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Command(abbreviation = "executeScheduledUpdate")
    public void executeScheduledUpdate() {
        try {
            final String updateUrl = Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.updatesUrl");
            UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(null, true, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

When I call "updateChecker", I can see the new version of the installer file on my server.
When I call "isUpdatedScheduled", it always returns false.
When I call "executeScheduledUpdate", it does nothing.


When I call "isUpdatedScheduled", it always returns false.
When I call "executeScheduledUpdate", it does nothing.

An update is "scheduled" by the background update downloader. You can add a background update downloader to your project on the Installer->Screens & Actions step. See the "Launcher integrations" tab of the background updater on how to start it programmatically from your service.
The concepts of background updates are explained here. You can look at the "hello" sample app to see how to invoke a background updater programmaticall and execute a scheduled update.

I did add a background downloaded to the installer.  I have read everything backwards and forwards about the update process from their web site/help section.  I am unable to find the "hello" sample application.  I have looked on their maven repo, their web site and gitHub and done extensive google searches on where that sample application might be. install4j report for project "WhiteStarFilesServer"

The hello sample is in samples/hello in the install4j installation.
